If the sleep time of a function at first time differs from the second time, but the output is the same, is it still a idempotent function?
For example, if the sleep time of a function would change after first execution but the output remains unchanged, e.g.:
public static int myFunction(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(MyClass.IsCalledBefore?1:1000);
    } catch(Exception e){
    }
    MyClass.IsCalledBefore=true;
    return 0;
}

is still a idempotent function?

What is your definition of "idempotent"? The mathematical definition of idempotent is, roughly, "f(x) = f(f(x)) for all x", but the mathematical definition does not apply here because this is not a mathematical function – it has a side-effect. The HTTP definition is "the client cannot be held responsible for repeated side-effects", but the HTTP definition does not apply because this is not a HTTP Request.

@JörgWMittag I guess the definition that Wikipedia gives of idempotence for a function in imperative programming is the relevant one: "a subroutine with side effects is idempotent if multiple calls to the subroutine have the same effect on the system state as a single call".

@JörgWMittag I think this question asks us to define a conversational term, so asking to provide a definition is strange.

Can we change the delay of 1 to 0? I think the question would be more focused then.

Idempotent is also used with side effects. Say there is someone in your database with a name of “Smith”. You change the name to Jones, side effect. You change the name to Jones a second time, same side effect. Changing the name ones or twice has the same effect, therefore idempotent.

@J_H The wikipedia page you linked to for idempotency contains almost an exact quote of the person you're objecting to, namely: "In the monoid of the functions from a set to itself, idempotent elements are the functions... such that f(f(x)) = f(x) for all x". I think Jörg was shooting for exactly what they said.

Yet another point in this discussion: Compilers may decide to optimizeiterated  idempotent function calls to a single call. Or perhaps rather: In the context of compiler design, the concept of "idempotent function" may be adjusted to mean precisely that. But any function that yields is certainly not equivalent to a non-yielding function; hence sleeping twice in a row (no matter if for differnt or same timespans) is by itself not the same as sleeping only once ...

"If the output is the same" - a function which prints output to a sheet of paper is NOT idempotent. Because you call it twice, you get two sheets of paper instead of one.

This is really a matter of definition, but to me if the execution time matters at all for idempotence then to be most strictly idempotent the second call to the function should take zero or negligible time, to make the following two snippets equivalent.
myFunction();

myFunction();
myFunction();

Idempotence doesn't mean that the function does the same thing each time it's called, it means that calling it twice is functionally the same as calling it once.

The function you reference is idempotent. The relevant definition of idempotent is (per Wikipedia):

a subroutine with side effects is idempotent if multiple calls to the subroutine have the same effect on the system state as a single call

Note: that the second definition given does not apply here because it is about functions without side-effects.  Also note that in this context, it is not just the result of the function that matters, it's the resulting state of the system i.e. side-effects.
This meaning of idempotence is defined in terms of 'state'. The definition of 'state' does not include execution times. The state of a system can only be determined at a point in time. If changes in execution time were an aspect of state, techniques such as memoization could not be considered valid in pure functional programming. Expanding the concept of state to include execution times simply muddies the meaning of the term.
That isn't to say that execution times are not relevant. There are known security implications to changing execution times. Processes with consistent execution times are called 'constant-time algorithms'. Whether a function (or algorithm) executes in constant time (not to be confused with constant time-complexity) may be related to state changes but it need not be. The execution time of a pure function can be (and usually is) dependent on its inputs.
After thinking about some of the comments on this answer and how they relate to the original question, I think a simpler and more obvious question is: does implementing a cache (or memoization) make a function stateful? Consider HTTP GET. Per the relevant RFC, a GET call is 'safe'. That means it is not only idempotent but (roughly) that it will not create any side effect at all. One of the advantages of this is that it allows for caching on the client and/or between the client and the client and host server. The main point of caching is to reduce the time of retrieval. But if that change response time is a state change, the call is no longer (strictly) safe. This is inherently a contradiction in terms. If you want to argue (as some have) that HTTP isn't generic enough, the same argument applies to memoization (basically: internal caching) of pure functions.

"the definition of 'state' does not include execution times." - I disagree. The definition of the system state depends on the system under discussion, there is no universal definition. It may include the processor clock, although usually it doesn't.

@Bergi The state of the system clock is not a duration. The concept of the state of a system is inherently a point-in-time concept.   You can talk about the state of a system changing (or not changing) over time.

@Bergi I would also argue that the system clock state is treated as an input in most programming situations. The obvious exception would be an operation that modifies the system time.

Sure the system time itself is not a duration, but taking the clock counter into account for the system state means it'll have changed during the execution of the function and the duration will become observable. And execution of anything requires clocks ticks, you can't have an operation that doesn't result in a change of the program counter :-) But yes, I totally agree that in most programming situations we do not want to consider this as part of the system state, as it's useless to argue about - I'm just saying that it isn't universal to never include it.

@Bergi I get what you are saying and it's not wrong, per se. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be a workable way to define state. If we take the system clock to be part of the state changed by a function, the whole idea of a 'pure' function becomes impossible on any machine with a clock. The concept of (state) 'idempotence' would meaningless: regardless of whether the duration changes (as in the example) from call to call, 2 calls with the same inputs at different points in time would always result in a different state. Even not calling the function would result in a state change.

It's not a useful definition of state when arguing about purity or idempotence, yes. But it is useful in other cases, e.g. when arguing about the equivalence between the functions x() { a = 1; b = 2; } and y() { b = 2; a = 1; }. That's why we need to define state on a case-by-case basis, just like we need to define what equivalence means for referential transparency. It may have to involve a concept of time (or at least order), and the blanket statement "state does not include times" is wrong.

@Bergi I didn't say state doesn't include times. I said it doesn't include 'execution times'.  The duration of a call is not part of either application or system state.  The state of the system clock is part of the system state but the system clock doesn't track durations.

@JimmyJames: In most cases, it makes sense to describe actions' effects on the observable state of the system, recognizing that things that are not considered observable within a system may be observable via means outside it, and some things may be considered observable whether or not there's any actual mechanism via which they could be observed.

@supercat OK. I'm not sure if you are calling out some aspect of the answer as needing improvement or not. Are you continuing the discussion I'm having with Bergi or is this a separate line of discussion?

@JimmyJames: A bit of both.  If a system defines a mechanism via which a task running on that system could find out how much time had elapsed between two operations, then the passage of time would represent an observable change of state.  The fact that human outside the system might be able to use a manual stopwatch to accomplish that, however, would not imply that time was "observable" within it.

@supercat This is a question of terminology. I don't think it is normal or useful to consider the passage of time to be a state change, at least from an application perspective.  The current time is treated as an input to applications in most cases. Just as the inputs from a sensor may be different depending on when you check, the 'time sensor' is going to provide a different input to the application depending on when it is checked. If we treat time as a state change, terms like 'pure functions' and 'idempotency' become nonsensical. Are you arguing that these terms are meaningless?

@JimmyJames: Whether or not it should represent a state change depends upon what the application is supposed to be doing.  Some kinds of application may require that things be done within certain timing windows, and a function may be specified as returning immediately if a certain amount of time remains in the present window, or else waiting until the start of the next window.  While I agree time isn't usually considered part of state, there are some kinds of application for which it very much would be.

@JimmyJames: Reasoning about situations like the time-window example generally works best in scenarios where the time required to perform individual actions will be small relative to the remaining time being tested for, so each action may be viewed as potentially shifting the state from "more than X time remaining in current window" to "less than X time remaining", and waiting for the start of the next window would reset the state to "more than X time remaining".

@supercat " While I agree time isn't usually considered part of state, there are some kinds of application for which it very much would be" Can you give some examples of those kinds of applications?  Concrete ones, preferably.

@JimmyJames: Low-level USB communication could probably qualify.  Depending upon the nature of the hardware USB subsystem, it may be most convenient to simply load data into buffers that will be transmitted at the first opportunity, but it may also be advantageous to know whether a packet will be sent in the current frame or the next frame, so that if the host changes its mind about what information it wants a device to send, the device won't waste time sending data that's not going to be wanted.

@Bergi By your definition, a stateless system could only exist if its execution time was instantaneous (i.e. no measurable execution time whatsoever), which is nonsensical.

@Flater No, it's exactly that: if your system state does not model time, then execution time is not measurable and all computations are equivalently instantaneous. Which is useful if we don't care. Notice that I am not advocating any particular definition of state: my point is only to never say never, and that when arguing about properties of programs we select a subset of the state of the theoretical or real-world model of computation that is relevant for the particular problem at hand. The choice of that subset should always be made clear, it sometimes will include time and sometimes not.

@Bergi: You're making up definitions as you go. No, having a process that doesn't look at the clock in and of itself does not mean that its runtime is effectively instantaneous. Stop inventing new definitions for words. None of this productively contributes to the question and answers posted here.

@Flater I was not talking about "a process that doesn't look at the clock". I was talking about a system where there is no clock. Of course this is not a physical system, it's a model. Which is the whole point: there are multiple ways to model computation, and they're useful for different things. To be productive, one has to be explicit about the precise system boundaries.

@supercat I'm not sure I understand how duration is a state there. The buffer has state to be sure. Is that not enough to describe the state of the subsystem? In other words, if the duration of an interaction is necessary to describe the state, it would need to be stored somewhere (which is clearly state) or if it's not stored, then we must conclude it is unnecessary to describe the state of the subsystem.

@JimmyJames: The "duration" is not a state in and of itself, but "time remaining until next window closure" is, and an action that took time T would advance that state by T (or cause it to wrap around if it would hit zero).  Actions would generally be modeled as advancing the state by some random amount between 0 and some maximum.  If a program was going to perform a sequence of actions, many of which had a maximum time that was extremely short relative to the window time, and if determination of the actual remaining window time was non-trivial, it would sometimes be useful...

...to have a function which would memoize the "time remaining" as 'estimated minimum time remaining', which would be adjusted downward when queried.  As someone who understands hardware and software principles, I'd rather have a timer that requires a do {read1 = TMR->VALUE; read2=TMR->VALUE; } while(read1 != read2); sequence than one that requires a hundreds-of-microseconds synchronization procedure to perform a read, but given only the latter, memoization can sometimes be useful even when modeling time.

@supercat I tried to move this to chat but something went sideways. There's a lot in your responses here that I don't really have time to address, unfortunately, and we've already exceeded what we should be adding as comments. But w/ regard to: "time remaining until next window closure". I think this kind of thing becomes challenging to discuss because state can mean a lot of things. For example, a 'stateless service' has state in the context of its execution and may persist state in a DB. The 'ephemeral' state isn't what we are talking about when we say 'stateless'.

In short
Depending on your definition, either your function is idempotent or no function at all is idempotent.
Some more arguments
Idempotence is about producing the same result even when applied multiple times in a row.
Let's take an engineering example where the results that matters is obvious. Take an elevator: I can press multiple times the same "floor 3" button, and in the end the operation will always bring me to floor 3, the intended result. Perhaps due to some extrinsic factors it will stop at an other intermediate floor. Maybe it will take  more or less time to arrive there depending on the departure floor. The operation "go to level 3" is nevertheless idempotent: should I press it several times in a row, it will still give the same result.
Back to computer science. Of course, it all depends on what you consider to be part of your result space:

If it is only the return value of the function, your function is idempotent.
If timing is an essential part of the expected result, it is not at all idempotent. And even if the time to return would always be identical, because invoking it two time on the row would mean that it already takes twice the time. In fact if you include time in the result space, no function is anymore idempotent, as invoking it several times in a row takes more time, which contradicts your definition (you could at best claim about "allost idempotent" for functions that have a very neglectable curation.

Conclusion
To leave idempotence any useful meaning, the best is therefore to focus on functional results and consider your function as idempotent. Invent another concept for the timing effect, but define it  precise enough, as the reasoning shows that it can become easily ambiguous.

"In fact if you include time in the result space, no function is anymore idempotent" -
I guess in some cases we could imagine a compiler detecting that the second call is unnecessary and automatically erasing it from object code, which would make the function idempotent.

OP is clearly interested in execution times. I don't like the conclusion.

@bdsl this is a strong point. We are therewith confronted to a time-space dilemma ;-)

@Basilevs I understand that OP is interested in execution times and that's exactly my point: idempotence cannot be about execution time unless super smart compilers could do memoisation on the flow as suggested by bdsl. In fact my argument is not about liking or not, it's a logical conclusion applying the possible definitions. If OP comes up with a definition in which idempotence covers the case of identical execution time, and eliminates the case that do not apply I'll revise my answer accordingly (but will certainly raise the paradoxes of discrete time vs continuous time)

By the way, looking at the snippet and seeing isCalledBefore() I guess that the whole matter is not about idempotence but about reproductibility and inter-process/thread synchronicity in a concurrent context, where concepts such as idempotence will not really help

@Christophe I believe OP is really trying to ask what the accepted definition of the word is, so they probably won't come up with a definition unless they choose to effectively answer their own question. It's really a language question rather than a practical software engineering question.

@bdsl I get this. And I am trying to explain that idempotence cannot cover execution time. This is a logical consequence of its definition.  The definition itself comes from the math where time plays no role. And here the point: even playing with the words,  there is no know and generally accepted definition of idempotence that covers execution time.

Technically, idempotence can cover execution time, but only if the (underlying function + invoking it) is instantaneous. :-)

@MateenUlhaq that's exactly my reasoning. But a function that is instantaneous is rather a rare exception than something common ;-)

Clearly this is depends on magnitude.
For some tasks, a speed difference of one second might be a difference like night and day (or even between life and death). For others it could be totally inconsequential. So whether you model "idempotence" as being affected by this depends on how big the difference is, and on how sensitive to delay your task is.
(I realize that there are sources who define idempotence as not being about execution speed, ever, but surely that is hard to follow in the real world. There's always a point at which a function becomes so slow as to be effectively unavailable.)

Also security - there is a wide range of timing-based attacks, that derive the system state from response times. So run time is effectively a part of the return value. Even small timing differences are a fatal bug in a security/information leak context.

@Basilevs, even aside from security concerns, all operations and calls should be regarded theoretically as having a time budget as an input (either implicit as a design assumption, or sometimes explicit as a timeout argument), and an actual execution time as an output (again either implicit as something that can be measured by the entry and return times, or perhaps occasionally explicit in the form of logging or status messages).

"sources who define idempotence as not being about execution speed" Are there sources that do define it as being about execution speed?  Please provide any you are aware of. We have other terms we can use. There's no need to hijack terms to make them less specific.

“Idempotent” means really “you don’t have to worry whether you do it once, or twice, or ten times, as long as you do it at least once”. If you try to unlock my iPhone with the wrong passcode, after five failed attempts there is a delay. After ten attempts the delay is two hours. You’d have to worry about that, even though the state doesn’t change other than for the execution time.

@gnasher729 And yet the result is the same: After each failed attempt, the phone remains locked ...

@gnasher729 And so the state does change, as the phone remembers the number of attempts or the delay for the next attempt. If you want to look only at the state other than that, then indeed you don't worry about it.

After the first failed attempt, the phone can be unlocked instantly. After the tenth attempt, it cannot be unlocked for two hours. Only looking at the internal state is misleading, it is a complete system.

Yes, the function itself is idempotent because there are seemingly no additional unintended side-effects when the function is called repeatedly - i.e. final state of the program is the same after calling the function again, and way the function is written seems to suggest that the side-effect of modifying the sleep time is intentional so would likely be expected by the caller (though it is important that the caller should be aware of this).
Related question on StackOverflow:  language agnostic - What is an idempotent operation?

Note: others in the thread have pointed out that there is no one 'true' definition of idempotence as it depends on context.    Given that the question as currently written doesn't give any clues over the significance of the sleep duration nor the importance of execution time, there is no way from the question to be sure exactly which of the multiple definitions of idempotence the question is asking about.

Program - yes, system - no.

@Basilevs The example function in the question is not modifying anything external to the program;  I'd say that any statements surrounding the state of the system are out-of-scope of the question here as that would depend on things outside of the function, and not mentioned in the question.

if the function just has a known range of random times it takes, then id say it's idempotent. But here it deliberately behaves differently. I know it's just an example but I think it begs the question

@BenCottrell when in doubt, I tend to focus on security. From security standpoint, execution time leaks information and is therefore a part of function effect. I know that the question does not seem to be concerned with security, but it is an overarching concern. There is no YAGNI in security.

Oops, I did not notice, that subsequent calls to the function are short in comparison to the first (only 1ms). So change of the system is not a significant one.

@Basilevs The issue there is that every single question across this entire site could be reinterpreted by expanding its scope far beyond anything that the asker had probably intended,  which would invalidate every single possible answer to every possible question -- it would render the entire site completely useless if every answer has to consider things which are completely out-of-scope of the question. and wouldn't help the people asking (nor anyone else for that matter).    Indeed, the site's guidelines deliberately encourage askers to narrow down the scope to stop this happening.

Do we really think that "there is no one 'true' definition of idempotence"?  It seems to me that, in the context of computing, 'idempotence' is clear and well defined. What evidence exists that there are different definitions in this context?

@JimmyJames I think the range of answers and comments in this Q+A thread suggest it's on the perspective from which someone is looking at it.    For example, there's the perspective of an end-user who might be happy with some brief delay if it doesn't affect the actual functional behaviour which they really care about - it may simply be "If I do X multiple times, then the program always gives me Y".  In contrast, with someone who might have written a unit test and somehow mocked out the call to Thread.sleep will notice their mock will receive different arguments in the first and second call

"will notice their mock will receive different arguments in the first and second call" But whether a function called during the execution of an idempotent method has different arguments (or if it is called at all) has nothing to do with idempotence. The only requirement is that the state of the system be the same after one or many calls with the same inputs. I don't see any value in making clear definitions murky, it makes terminology less useful.


Definition. A function f is idempotent if f(f(x)) = f(x).

...Let's look at different fs.

Is f(x) = myFunction() idempotent?
Yes. Proof:
f always returns 0. Thus,
f(f(x)) = f(0) = 0 = f(x)


Is f((_, world_state)) = (myFunction(), get_world_state()) idempotent?
No. The world_state (which includes the current time) changes. Proof:
Let x = (_, WorldState(time=0)).
Then,
f(f(x))
  = f(f((_, WorldState(time=0))))
  = f((0, WorldState(time=1000)))
  = (0, WorldState(time=1001))

However, this does not equal
(0, WorldState(time=1000))
  = f((_, WorldState(time=0)))
  = f(x)


Is f((was_called, _, _)) = (True, myFunction(), time_elapsed_by_previous_function_call()) idempotent?
No. Proof:
Let x = (False, _, _).
Then,
f(f(x))
  = f(f((False, _, _)))
  = f((True, 0, 1000))
  = (True, 0, 1)

However, this does not equal
(True, 0, 1000)
  = f((False, _, _))
  = f(x)


The source code of function is in the question.

Timing and system clock state are important in context of this question. I therefore reject hypotheticals about mathematical purity.
If our only concern is inexact system clock which can't measure 1ms intervals, the the second invocation of the function does nothing making the function idempotent.
However, from a security perspective an additional context switch caused by Thread.sleep() is a major effect. Therefore, for the function to be idempotent in a full sense, it has to eliminate a call to Thread.sleep() from subsequent calls:
    public static int myFunction(){
        try {
            if (!MyClass.IsCalledBefore) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
        }
        MyClass.IsCalledBefore=true;
        return 0;
    }

